# libav - Output segmented stream recording with the current timestamp

Tags: linux, bash, video, ffmpeg, libav

I'm making a DIY DVR (using Linux Mint) for my D-LINK IPCAM, and after some searches on internet i found a solution which better suit my needs: avconv.

I learn of this command to record a stream in segmented videos:

```
avconv -i rtsp://<user>:<password>@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/play1.sdp -c copy -map 0 -f segment -segment_time 300 -segment_format mp4 "capture-%03d.mp4"
```

...but the only problem is apparently the naming scheme is sequential (like output-001.mp4), and i need to get the current date and time the video is finished (like output-08-12-2017_16-55).

Is possible to make this only using bash and avconv or i will need to resort to other tools?

Comment: Why do you need segmented output? Couldn't you save everything to a single file? (Note that `avconv` is not `ffmpeg`.)

Comment: Yeah sorry for the confusion, but i need autosegmented videos because i plan to record 24/7 from a security camera, so i need to delete the videos older than 1 week to prevent the hdd (500gb) to become full.

Comment: Possible with ffmpeg. Doesn't appear possible with Libav.

Comment: Really? I searched a lot for a ffmpeg solution but didnt find anything meaningful.

Comment: With ffmpeg, you can add `-strftime 1` and a formatted string in the output name.

Comment: Check if `mediainfo` reports "Encoded date" or "Tagged date" for the MP4 files (`mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Encoded_Date%" $the_file`). If so it is a SMOP to rename them afterwards with a script.

Comment: @Mulvya thanks for the ffmpeg tip, i make a self-answer describing how i did the command with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Mulvya, I've managed to achieve this by using ffmpeg:

`ffmpeg -i rtsp://<user>:<password>@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/play1.sdp -c copy -map 0 -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 1800 -segment_format mp4 out-%d_%m_%Y-%H_%M_%S.mp4`